# backslash apostrophe inside and outside of commands

Tags: errors

I don't understand why LaTeX gives a runaway argument error with

`{a\'}`

but not with

`\texttt{a\'}`

or

`\emph{a\'}`

Can anyone explain?  When an argument is provided (e.g. `\'e`), it works the same inside and outside commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\'` requires an argument so

```
{a\'}
```

is an error, but

```
\texttt{a\'}
```

expands to (more or less)

```
{\tttfamily a\'\ifsomething\/\fi}
```

so `\'` isn't the last token in the group so it gets an unintended argument and by luck happens to not make an error.